# Зворотний чи зворотній (зв'язок)?

Tags: орфографія, spelling

Цитую [онлайнкоректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/):

> За Правописом (§23 1) прикметник зворотний вживається із суфіксом
>   -н(ий), тому відмінюється як прикметник твердої групи (Правопис §68).
>
> НЕПРАВИЛЬНО:
>
> Ми хочемо отримати від вас **зворотній** зв’язок.
>
> ПРАВИЛЬНО:
>
> Ми хочемо отримати від вас **зворотний** зв’язок.

Проте за пошуком ["зворотній зв'язок"](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA%22&*) можна знайти велику кількість сайтів, що використовують саме таке написання.

Як правильно?

Comment: В правописі не вказано, що конкретно цей прикметник потрібно вживати із суфіксом -н(ий). Тому онлайнкоректор каже неправду.

Comment: Орфографічні та орфоепічні словники пишуть _зворотний_, СУМ пише _зворотний_, які проблеми?

Comment: Проблеми в тому, що всі пишуть "зворотній".

Comment: @sashaeve, виходить — що м'які варіанти більш притаманні українській мові і вона поступово до них повертається — особливо в тих місцях, де немає прямого збігу з російськими словами — «зворотній», або навпаки треба від нього відмежуватися — «природній», «дружній».

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Про кожну пару

#### «Природний» та «природній»

У мене і [деяких](http://www.ukrcenter.com/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC/31307/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%94%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%94%D0%9D%D0%AC%D0%9E%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8F#118123) [інших](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=2845.msg298285#msg298285) користувачів інтернету, наприклад, було склалося враження, що ці слова відрізняються за семантикою:

- природний — це такий, що має відношення до рослинно-тваринно-неорганічного світу Землі (*<sub>рос.</sub>* природный);
- природній — це справжній, натуральний, незмінений (антонім до «штучний»; *<sub>рос.</sub>* естественный).

Але словники такого розрізнення не подають. Більшість словників (наприклад, [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryrodnyj)) надає весь спектр значень слову «природний» (а слова «природній» не містять). Деякі (наприклад, [Ніковський](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9&scope=ukr&dicts=8&highlight=on) — 1927, [Якубські](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9&scope=ukr&dicts=13&highlight=on) — 1928, Шелудько/Садовський — 1928, Козирський/Шендеровський — 1996) містять лише «природній» (в усіх значеннях). Деякі містять обидва слова — але різницю у значеннях виявити важко.

#### «Зворотний» та «зворотній»

Слово «зворотн(и/і)й» більшість словників подає як «[зворотний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35067&page=1114)». Варіант «зворотній» я бачу значно рідше (навіть порівняно з пропорцією «природній» до «природний») — поки що лише [у Ніковського (1927)](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all) та Козирського/Шендеровського (1996). Зате «[воротній](http://sum.in.ua/s/vorotnij)» пишеться через «і» всюди (навіть у СУМ; але «ворітн{и/і}й» — знову по-різному).

Семантичну різницю знайти, чи хоча б вигадати, тут ще важче.

#### «Народний» та «народній»

Також є [народній](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F"&num=100). Наприклад, [газета «Народня воля»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F_(%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)) або [Українська народня республіка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B2.D0.B0) (саме так воно тоді писалось). Ось що [пише](http://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/148804.html?thread=1937732#t1937732) з цього приводу maksymus, що веде блог про українську мову «ua-etymology» у livejournal:

> Під час правописних реформ 1920-х надуживали пом’якшенням, вважаючи це народною мовою. Сьогодні повертаються до тих помилок. В цьому випадку основним було *природний* (Грінченко, Недільський) з варіантом *природній* (Голоскевич подає тільки *природний*, Кримський вагається — *природни[і]й*).

Іншої думки дотримується Караванський, вважаючи, що правопис 1928 року визнав тверді форми всупереч мовній практиці і «українським прикметникам притаманніший м'який варіянт» ([«Секрети української мови»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Karavanskyy_Sviatoslav/Sekrety_ukrainskoi_movy/), 1994, Київ).

## Висновки

#### Норма і побут

За словниками і офіційним правописом правильно: *природний*, *зворотний*, *народний*.

Тим не менш м'які варіанти написання (що колись уже були навіть в побуті) поступово знову проникають в ужиток (у тій чи іншій мірі для різних слів). Деякі «народні» словники починають їх фіксувати: [slovnyk.ua](http://slovnyk.ua/?swrd=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9), [народний сучасний r2u](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9&scope=ukr&dicts=10&highlight=on), [загальний народний e2u](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9&dicts=1&highlight=on), [словник синонімів Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53405/268483.html). Мені здається, що рано чи пізно м'які написання відвоюють собі місце.

#### Щодо семантичної різниці

Ніякої семантичної різниці офіційно нема.

Проте у випадку *прородного* і *природнього*, мені здається, що вона має шанс з'явитися, але ще не визріла. Пошук у лейпцизькому корпусі 2014 серед сусідів для «[природний](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)» показує, наприклад, «заповідник»:«колір» у пропорції 3:1, а для «[природній](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9)» — вони ж у співвідношенні 1:5. Я припускаю про себе, що маю охоту писати «природний» у тих випадках, де у росіян те саме слово, і «природній» — в усіх інших (як більш притаманну форму, коли ззовні нічого не впливає — чи, може, навпаки, хочеться відмежуватися від невірної конотації).

Прецедент: «[дружний](http://sum.in.ua/s/druzhnyj)» (*<sub>рос.</sub>* дружный) і «[дружній](http://sum.in.ua/s/druzhnij)» (*<sub>рос.</sub>* дружеский) — визнано СУМ-11.

#### Додаткова інформація (посилання)

- [зведена таблиця для «природний»/«природній»/«зворотний»/«зворотній» по словниках](//brownian.org.ua/?p=13);
- пошук на r2u: «[природний](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=ukrq&highlight=on)», «[природній](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9&scope=ukrq&highlight=on)»;
- [О. Пономарів про «природн{и/і}й»](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/2010/12/post-36.html);
- обговорення на slovnyk.net: [перше](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t290), [друге](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t2589.html);
- [обговорення на lingvoforum](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=2845).

P.S.: Щоби працював пошук: «природно», «природньо».

P.P.S.: «[кутній](http://sum.in.ua/s/kutnij)» і «[трикутний](http://sum.in.ua/s/trykutnyj)» («[трикутній](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9&scope=ukrq&highlight=on)»).

Answer (score 4):

Саме так, *зворотний* — це [правильна](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) [форма](http://sum.in.ua/s/zvorotnyj).

Натомість слово *зворотній* може бути використане лише в давальному або місцевому відмінках жіночого роду однини:

> (Н) зворотна адреса — (Д) зворотній адресі — (М) у зворотній адресі

Такий же термін [використовує](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA) Вікі.